# What is Stewart's Theorem?

Tags: contest-math

What is Stewart's Theorem? I know it has something to do with triangles. I saw it being mentioned in a MathCounts practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it is a way to relate the cevian of a triangle to the side lengths of the triangle, as well as the lengths of the two segments which the cevian cuts.

[image]

The formula is easy to remember as dad + man = bmb + cnc.

Comment: You forgot to write out the actual mnemonic! "A **man** and his **dad** put a **bomb** (bmb) in the **sink** (cnc)."